# Script works from command-line, not from package.json script

Tags: node.js

The following:

```
npx nodemon --watch './**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node-esm ./src/server.ts'
```

works from the command-line at the root folder of my project. But when I try to use it as a script in `package.json`:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev:erver": "npx nodemon --watch './**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node-esm ./src/server.ts'"
    }
}
```

it fails with the following:

```
[nodemon] 3.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): '.\**\*.ts'
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `'ts-node-esm ./src/server.ts'`

''ts-node-esm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try running `which ts-node-esm`, and also try replacing the `--exec ...` argument with `--exec 'echo $PATH'`, see what you get.